# Laravel edit data with using id in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, forms

I want to list datas when I click tasks on the right side as edit section.

I cannot put the value of the clicked data into the input. And if it displays, it always shows the last index of array.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
   id="show-task"
   onclick="showDiv('edittaskk')"
   data-url="{{ route('as.show', $as->id) }}"><span class="task-title">{{$as->title}}</span></a>
```

```
Route::get('as/{id}', [HomeController::class, 'show'])->name('as.show');
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        /* When click show user */
        $('body').on('click', '#show-task', function () {
            var taskURL = $(this).data('url');
            $.get(taskURL, function (data) {
                $('#edittask').modal('show');
                $('#as-id').text(data.id);
                $('#as-title').text(data.title);
                $('#as-duedate').text(data.duedate);
                $('#as-status').text(data.status);
                $('#as-prio').text(data.prio);
            })
        });

    });

</script>
```

```
<div class="task-list-desc d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <form action="{{route('edittask',['id'=>$as->id])}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <p><strong>Title:</strong> <span id="as-title"></span><div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16">
                    <input class="input100"  name="title[]"  value="{{$as['title']}}" type="text">

                </div>
                <p><strong>DueDate:</strong> <span id="as-duedate"></span><div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16">

                    <input class="input100" name="duedate" value="{{$as->duedate}}" type="date">
```

Comment: If you are supposed to have _multiple_ such links on the same page - then you must of course not use `id="show-task"` on all of them, IDs must be unique.

Comment: What is `onclick="showDiv('edittaskk')"` supposed to be? Aren't you binding the click handlers for this with `$('body').on('click', '#show-task', function () {`?